# Non-prime-generating polynomial

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Is there a polynomial, which generates only composites and never primes? I only need a theoretic proof, no need for the actual polynomial. It can have non-integer coefficients.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean $(n^2-n+41)\cdot 2$ is always generating composite numbers?

Comment: If you want a monic polynomial how about $x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$? Its values are always multiples of $6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many solutions. For example, the polynomial
$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+...+a_1x^1$$
is always composite if $x>1$ is an integer an at least two of the sequence $a_k$ are nonzero. Also, if the elements of $a_k$ share a common factor other than $1$, the polynomial $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+...+a_1x^1+a_0$
is composite.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is an integer, then $4x^2+4$ is a positive multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is an integer, $x^2$ is never a prime.